# prevent default on enter keypress in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm solving the problem with default submit button in IE7. When I press "enter" key in input field, than some button on the page is clicked. So I've found the solution for this:

```
 $(document).bind("keypress", function(ev) {
     ev.keyCode == 13 && ev.preventDefault();  
 });
```

But there is the problem with this code: textarea tag don't get "new line". So I tried this:

```
 $(document).bind("keypress", function(ev) {
     if (ev.keyCode == 13 && ev.target.type != "textarea")
         ev.preventDefault();  
 });
```

It works but looks dirty. The question is: can you advice better solution for the Problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is to simply prevent the form submission on enter keypress, test on the keypress when the form is trying to submit...

```
$(your_form).submit(function(ev){
    if (ev.keyCode == 13){
        // Prevent form submission behaviors if the event was fired by enter keypress
        ev.preventDefault();return false;
    }
    // And code for form submission here, or just keep the return true to make it behave normally.
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not dirty. But if you want one line, you still could do with:

```
ev.keyCode == 13 && ev.target.type != "textarea" && ev.preventDefault();
```

Comment: The problem with the textarea was a pitfall for me. I afraid another pitfalls with preventing default keypress handling. Problem with the solution that it solves the problem by globally disabling ENTER handling. And if W3C would add new control to the standard, I need to find and change this code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution would be to use [jQuery's submit handler](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and return false:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(ev){
  // custom form handling code here

  return false;// prevent browser default form submission
});
```

Alternatively, you could also call `.preventDefault()` on the event object, passed in to the submit handler.